# Can't figure out why my program is asserting

Tags: c, memory, assertion

I'm working on an simple vector program as an assignment, but I cant figure out my why program asserts. My program compiles successfully, but fails at runtime. I think im at the reach of expertise on this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#define TESTING
using namespace std;
typedef float Elem;//floats for vector elements

struct Vector{//structure for the vector
    unsigned int size;
    Elem *svector;
};


int main(){

#ifdef TESTING
        //prototypes
    Vector *alloc_vec();
    bool print_vec(Vector *printVector);
    Vector *extend_vec(Vector *extend,Elem element);
    Vector *scalar_plus(Vector *vecToAdd, Elem addElement);
    void dealloc_vec(Vector *&deAlloc);

    //testing scaffolds
    Vector *testVec=new Vector;
    *testVec=*alloc_vec();
    assert(testVec->size==0);
    assert(testVec->svector==NULL);

    for(int i=0;i=10;i++){
        *testVec=*extend_vec(testVec,Elem(i));
    }

    assert(testVec->size!=0);
    assert(testVec->svector!=NULL);

    assert(print_vec(testVec));
    print_vec(testVec);

    *testVec=*scalar_plus(testVec,5);

    print_vec(testVec);

    dealloc_vec(testVec);

    assert(testVec==NULL);
#endif //testing

    return 0;
}

Vector *alloc_vec(){//constructor to allocate an empty (zero-length) vector
    Vector *newVector=new Vector; //initiatizes a new vector
        if (newVector==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    newVector->size=0;//sets length to 0 
    newVector->svector=NULL;//sets vector to null


    return newVector;
}

bool print_vec(Vector *printVector){

    if(printVector==NULL){//makes sure printVector exists to pass unit test 1
        return false;
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<printVector->size;i++){
        cout<<printVector->svector[i]<<endl;
    }

    return true;

}

void dealloc_vec(Vector *deAlloc){
    if (deAlloc==NULL){//if the vector contains no memory, no need to deallocate, unit test#1
        return;}

    delete deAlloc;//clears the memory of the vector
    deAlloc=NULL;
    return;

}

Vector *extend_vec(Vector *extend,Elem element){
    if (extend==NULL){
        return NULL;}


    Elem *tempVec=new Elem[extend->size+1];//sets up a temp vector one size larger
    tempVec[extend->size]=element;

    memcpy(tempVec,extend->svector,(extend->size*sizeof(Elem)));//copies the memory from the original array to the rest of the temp array

        extend->size+=1;

    delete[] extend->svector;//clears the memory

    extend->svector=tempVec;//the original vector now becomes the extended vector

    delete[] tempVec;//clears the temporary memory

        return extend;
}

Vector *scalar_plus(Vector *vecToAdd, Elem addElement){
    if (vecToAdd==NULL){
        return NULL;}
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<vecToAdd->size;i++){//adds a scalar to each element 
        vecToAdd->svector[i]+=addElement;
        }

        return vecToAdd;
}
```

**EDIT
Some people asked me which assertion error I got:

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program:
...12\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe

File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dggdel.cpp

Line:52

Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

I've also made the following changes:
    assert(testVec=NULL)
    (deAlloc==NULL)

to

```
assert(testVec==NULL)
(deAlloc==NULL)
```

this function from:
    void dealloc_vec(Vector *deAlloc)

to:

void dealloc_vec(Vector *&deAlloc)

Assertion error fixed, however doesnt produce output. Still working on the debugging.

Also, quite possible this is more C than C++. My prof states in the assignment spec that this is C++, but he switches between the two lots in our class.

Comment: Please post the error message. There are probably people who can help you who don't have the time to copy/paste/compile/run your code and see the error message for themselves

Comment: So it's said, this isn't C++.  This is C being compiled by a C++ compiler.  Those functions you declare in `main`?  Those should be member functions of `Vector`.  :P

Comment: Your whole approach is so misguided. You keep making new Vectors in each function and copying their contents over the contents of testVec. You're looking all sorts of memory because you never delete the Vectors that you return from `alloc_vec` and `extend_vec`. You should write functions or member functions that modify the Vector in place, not return new Vectors that need to be copied.

Comment: Since you know **exactly** which line is asserting, it would really help if you would include that in your question. It vastly simplifies things, and would help avoid our having to wade through dozens of lines of code (and would get you answers more quickly). When posting in the future, remember that if you have information to make your question more clear, you should include it.

Comment: "Your whole approach is so misguided. You keep making new Vectors in each function and copying their contents over the contents of testVec. You're looking all sorts of memory because you never delete the Vectors that you return from alloc_vec and extend_vec. You should write functions or member functions that modify the Vector in place, not return new Vectors that need to be copied. – Barmar"

I'm working to assignment specification. These are the functions my prof requested, and this is the sort of style he asked for testing.

Comment: Really appreciating the help. I've added the edits you guys have suggested, but my error still exists. Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
assert(testVec=NULL);
```

will set `testVec` to `NULL` and evaluate as equal to that null pointer, which is false when treated as a boolean.

That should almost certainly be `assert(testVec == NULL);` instead.

For future reference, this is why so-called "Yoda conditions" (`NULL == testVec` rather than `testVec == NULL`) are sometimes preferred in C and C++ when comparing to a constant.  If you accidentally use `=` rather than `==`, Yoda conditions fail to compile, making the problem more obvious.

With that fixed, you have another problem:  `dealloc_vec` nulls out its local copy of the `Vector*`, but that's just a copy of the real pointer; the change doesn't make it back to the caller.  You might want to declare the function to take a `Vector*&` (a reference to a pointer).  Before you do that, though, you have another assignment-instead-of-comparison to fix:  `if (dealloc=NULL)` should be `if (dealloc == NULL)`.

What's more, the `delete[] tempvec;` in `extend_vec` frees memory you're still using.  You're begging for segfaults and heap corruption if you keep it.  So delete it.

Comment: The ol' accidentally using assignment instead of equality...subtle bug that will get you in C or C++ every time!

Comment: It wouldn't be as tricky if this were actually C++.  :P  That `testVec = NULL;` wouldn't even exist with proper objects and RAII.  Just saying.  :)

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 And other languages! Probably a mistake everyone makes once. I believe this was my first PHP bug way back when I'd never coded before. `if($x = 0)` :)

Comment: God, you guys are the best. I pull my hair out sometimes looking for small stuff like this.

Comment: @cHao:I made the change the pass the pointer by reference. Good change, but my program still fails with the assertion error stated.

Comment: The error looks like it's happening in the CRT.  Probably has to do with the rather screwy memory shuffling you're doing.  Lemme look it over a bit more.

Comment: @chao: The program, not longer asserts! Praise you! However, it produces no output, so I guess I'll still be looking it over.

Comment: @Keith: Yeah...that's kinda easy to fix too.  `for (int i=0;i=10;++i)` is a problem.  See the `i=10`?  That should probably be `i<10`.  When you say `i=10`, the loop condition always evaluates as 10 (which is truthy) so the loop runs forever.  You really really need to get the hang of comparison vs assignment... :)

Comment: @cHao: Yes, I found that through debugging. Also, through breakpoints I found that the memcpy() doesn't work as it supposed to.